How to one value come first during sort on that field Elastic Search
I use python and I sort data in alphabetical order,but only one data in there will not be sorted like that but put it at the top
I dont have solution for problem
example: I want to value = "Other Countries" comes first, any other data have to sort by alphabet
This is my query:
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "type": "COUNTRY"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "value": "**"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": []
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "country": {
                "order": "asc",
                "missing": "_first"
            }
        }
    ],
    "size": 10,
    "track_total_hits": true
}


This is my solution and it work
    "sort": [
    {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "if (params._source.country_code == 'OTHER_COUNTRY') { return 0; } else { return 1; }",
                "params": {
                    "multiplier": "OTHER_COUNTRY"
                }
            },
            "order": "asc"
        }
    },
    {
        "country": {
            "order": "asc",
            "missing": "_first"
        }
    }
],


For these documents
PUT /countries/_bulk?refresh
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"type":"COUNTRY","country_code":"Other Countries"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"type":"COUNTRY","country_code":"Vietnam"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"type":"COUNTRY","country_code":"Panama"}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"type":"COUNTRY","country_code":"Zambia"}
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"type":"COUNTRY","country_code":"Belgique"}

try the following modified query
GET /countries/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "type": "COUNTRY"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "constant_score": {
                                    "filter": {
                                        "term": {
                                            "country_code.keyword": {
                                                "value": "Other Countries"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "boost": 2
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "constant_score": {
                                    "filter": {
                                        "match_all": {}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": "desc"
        },
        {
            "country_code.keyword": {
                "order": "asc",
                "missing": "_first"
            }
        }
    ],
    "size": 10,
    "track_total_hits": true
}

For me the response contains these lines
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "countries",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 3.0870113,
                "_source" : {
                    "type" : "COUNTRY",
                    "country_code" : "Other Countries"
                },
                "sort" : [
                    3.0870113,
                    "Other Countries"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index" : "countries",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "5",
                "_score" : 1.0870113,
                "_source" : {
                    "type" : "COUNTRY",
                    "country_code" : "Belgique"
                },
                "sort" : [
                    1.0870113,
                    "Belgique"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index" : "countries",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : 1.0870113,
                "_source" : {
                    "type" : "COUNTRY",
                    "country_code" : "Panama"
                },
                "sort" : [
                    1.0870113,
                    "Panama"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index" : "countries",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 1.0870113,
                "_source" : {
                    "type" : "COUNTRY",
                    "country_code" : "Vietnam"
                },
                "sort" : [
                    1.0870113,
                    "Vietnam"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index" : "countries",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "4",
                "_score" : 1.0870113,
                "_source" : {
                    "type" : "COUNTRY",
                    "country_code" : "Zambia"
                },
                "sort" : [
                    1.0870113,
                    "Zambia"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}


it's a good ideal, but when i run your ideal, there is an error with it.
{
"error": {
"root_cause": [
{
"type": "query_shard_exception",
"reason": "No mapping found for [value.keyword] in order to sort on",
"index_uuid": "dK5J_AiASEeOUOLK8vyVig",
"index": "mobio-address-v1_0"
}
],

"sort": [
{
"_script": {
"type": "number",
"script": {
"lang": "painless",
"source": "if (params._source.country_code == 'OTHER_COUNTRY') { return 0; } else { return 1; }",
"params": {
"multiplier": "OTHER_COUNTRY"
}
},
"order": "asc"
}
},
{
"country": {
"order": "asc",
"missing": "_first"
}
}

@Nam Kiều Thanh, you should adapt my query to your mapping. A script is slower than a pure query. I've accelerated the query by constant_score
